# emitting message to specific user socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to emit my message to specific user in socket.io, like so:

in my array, I am holding the users `socket.id`. So I am calling it from the array like so, but it is not emitting to screen.

```
io.to(users[0].id).emit('new_message', {message : data.message, username : socket.username,color: socket.color});
```

any ideas?

Comment: This seems correct assuming, 1) `users[0].id` is not undefined, 2) `new_message` listening from client :)

Comment: it is defined, and new_message works, when I don't do `io.to`, which is strange?!

Comment: Well the docs specify that when you use it as `io.to() io.in()` it sends to a specific group or room, I'm using it all the time `io.to` works. I'm guessing something else is not working...